# Did I configured JSPM correctly for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, jspm

I create an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages app with SPA using JSPM

Having

default.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSPM</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body aurelia-app>
    <script src="packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="jspm.config.js"></script>
    <script src="jspm.dev.js"></script>
    <script >
        System.import('xperiandri/app.ts');
    </script>
    <!--<script>
        SystemJS.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

jspm.config.js

```js
SystemJS.config({
  paths: {
    "github:": "packages/github/",
    "npm:": "packages/npm/"
  },
  browserConfig: {
    "baseURL": "/",
    "paths": {
      "xperiandri/": "/"
    }
  },
  nodeConfig: {
    "paths": {
      "xperiandri/": ""
    }
  },
  transpiler: "plugin-typescript",
  typescriptOptions: {
    "module": "system",
    "target": "es6",
    "tsconfig": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  packages: {
    "xperiandri": {
      "main": "app.ts",
      "defaultExtension": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "plugin-typescript"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

app.ts

```js
export class App {
    constructor() {
        console.log("JSPM initialized");

        var textnode = document.createTextNode("Welcome JSPM!");
        document.body.appendChild(textnode);
    }
}
```

I expect to see tag with `Welcome JSPM!` text added to body but this does not happen.
What do I do wrong?

app.ts is downloaded by Microsoft Edge, checked in developer tools. However its media type is video, not text.

Request

`Accept: application/x-es-module, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: uk, ru; q=0.8, en-US; q=0.5, en; q=0.3
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost:41467
Referer: http://localhost:41467/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16275`

Response

`Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts
Date: Sun, 27 Aug 2017 22:01:34 GMT
ETag: "1d31766378d8152:-1"
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 14:36:31 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNc0JDQvdC00YDRltC5XERldlxYcGVyaUFuZHJpXEx5c292Lk1uZ1xzcmNcV2ViXGFwcC50cw==?=`

Answer (score 1):

If file was downloaded it means that mime types are wrong.

You need to add mime type for `ts` files `text/x.typescript` or `text/prs.typescript`

Try to add this in startup config

```
var fileProvider= new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
fileProvider.Mappings.Add(".ts", "text/x.typescript");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() { ContentTypeProvider = fileProvider});
```

Comment: Almost work
Layload now correct but has encoding issues
```ï»¿export class App {
    constructor() {
        console.log("JSPM initialized");

        var textnode = document.createTextNode("Welcome JSPM!");
        document.body.appendChild(textnode);
    }
}```

Comment: And it has to be replaced `fileProvider.Mappings[".ts"] = "text/x.typescript";` as this extension is already registered

Comment: Try to force utf 8 encoding

Comment: OK, I added `"text/prs.typescript; charset=utf-8"` instead of just `"text/prs.typescript"` and now payload copied from MS Edge correctly. Is it a right way of doing that, @volodymyr-bilyachat ?